# How to isolate heat from oven towards refrigerator?

Tags: refrigerator, oven, saving-money

While trying to take minor steps towards reducing the electricity consumption at our home, on an online forum (sorry can't recall the original source) I read that if the oven and the fridge are close to each other, the heat from the oven will make the fridge work harder and therefore use more energy -- this make immediate sense to me!

At home we have a setup where these two devices are close to each other, and there is no good isolation from the oven towards the fridge. What is the best way that I can isolate the heat radiating from the oven?

I thought of using styrofoam between the two devices, other suggestions included a big metal (steel) plate? Any other alternatives? What's best?

Comment: You understand that “heat radiating from the oven” will only affect the electricity consumption of the refrigerator WHEN THE REFRIGERATOR DOOR IS OPEN, don’t you?

Comment: How hot and for how long is your oven blasting heat  through the metal side, insulation and into your refrigerator ? Perhaps you could turn a fan on when you use the oven.

Comment: @LeeSam, that is untrue. Insulation in the side of the refrigerator is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A metal sheet, suspended between the surface of the stove and the fridge, would be safest, simplest and cheapest. Consider, though, how long the payback would be to the investment ROI): how often does the oven run, how much does it raise the temperature of the side of the 'fridge, and how much does electricity cost?

From the environmental standpoint, consider the energy used in fabricating a sheet of aluminum, and how much energy is saved.

For safety, do not apply insulation in a manner that would cause more heat to accumulate on a wall behind or next to the oven.

Answer (score 0):

I would **NOT** recommend anything that melts, burns or gives off nauseous gases. Like Styrofoam. If you feel you need to do something like this I would recommend something like a welding blanket. They are fairly inexpensive and can be found in most hardware stores that have welding supplies. Now all you have to do is figure out how to frame it up to fit between you appliances.

Another material could be fiberglass insulation with fire resistant backing.

Regardless, I am hoping this helps to point you in the right direction, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stovetop will be more of an issue than the oven, as the element is exposed directly to the fridge. You can try touching the side of the fridge when the oven is on, and when the stovetop is on to compare. I would recommend preferring the burners on the side of the stovetop away from the fridge; this is a simple improvement that doesn't cost money.

As for more permanent solutions, I don't think there's any good ones. You may be able to move cabinets around depending on your exact setup, but probably not. (Cabinets can be unattached then moved, but countertops can't be easily split, plus you need connections for the stove, and an outlet for the fridge.)